# How to get data from job before it ends?

Tags: powershell, output, jobs

I'm doing a project where I need to start jobs to do parallel processes. I'm using `Start-Job` to launch them, and I can get data on the end of the job with `Receive-Job`. The problem here is: the process is to copy files from directories and this process can takes long, so I need to check if processing is going OK or stacked somewhere, like a percentage (%) of files copied.

How can I check a variable value before the job ends?

Comment: `going OK or stacked somewhere` - stuck? (You do know the last % of work takes 137% of the time?)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Receive-Job` at any time. The job doesn't have to be finished for that. The received output is removed from the job, though, so you need to store it in a variable if you need it later on.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {1..10 | %{$_; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}}
PS C:\> Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
PS C:\> Receive-Job -Job $job
1
2
3
PS C:\> Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
PS C:\> Receive-Job -Job $job
4
5
6
PS C:\> $job.State
Running
```